# Connect to MySQL with CLI but not Magento

Tags: mysql, local.xml, mysql-config

I am getting the following error

```
SQLSTATE[HY000] [2003] Can't connect to MySQL server on '10.0.1.24' (13)

Trace:
#0 html/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php(111): Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Abstract->_connect()......
```

I have confirmed the PDO is installed.

I can connect via the CLI

```
[magento@web2 etc]# mysql -uuser -p'MyBigPassword' -h10.0.1.24 magento_prod
Reading table information for completion of table and column names
You can turn off this feature to get a quicker startup with -A

Welcome to the MariaDB monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
Your MariaDB connection id is 27
Server version: 5.5.44-MariaDB MariaDB Server

Copyright (c) 2000, 2015, Oracle, MariaDB Corporation Ab and others.

Type 'help;' or '\h' for help. Type '\c' to clear the current input statement.

MariaDB [magento_prod]>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was the hosting company having seLinux enabled and Apache could not read parts of the application. I disabled it and it works now